# How did photoshop store pixels data in layer form?

Tags: photoshop, layer

My school project is to duplicate photoshop layer's system using java. One of the thing I wonder about the layer system is how they store the pixels data? I could think of two ways of implementation: fixed size and larger fixed size with clipping. Because in either way layer is fixed, there will be loss in pixel data if the transformation exceeds the fixed size. I was thinking about dynamic size, but it can take out a lot of runtime. Therefore, I want to know how photoshop did it (I tried translate the layer's pixels outside the layer's border and after reselecting it again, no pixel was loss)

Answer (score 0):

Store each layer's size seperately, and store the size of the full image itself seperately as well. Then you will not lose information when the image clips certain layers.

Comment: If i make change, for e.g. painting brush, to a layer, wouldn't its size changes too? Do I have to recreate layer with new size everytime the picture is painted? I don't know how photoshop store pixel data for each separate layer, but I plan to store it in image form, so I have to create new image everytime I make a change that result in new size.